# R function to calculate weighted standard deviation

Tags: r, statistics

I am struggling to get R compute the weighted standard deviation. I want to get the weighted sd using the following equation:
[image]

However, the functions provided by R (wtd.var, weightedVar, etc.) all use this formula:
[image]

How can I get the weighted sd using the first equation in R? Thank you so much,

I tried wtd.var, weightedVar but the returned wvar values are not correct,
for example, [image]
wvar should be 2.16 and 1.16 for row1 and row2 respectively.

Comment: Just write your own function

Comment: I have a very large dataset, with 200 columns of values, and 200 columns of respective weights,around 10000 rows. There are NAs in the values columns, and I want R to omit NAs values and use the availblae info to compute the weighted means. I am not sure how I can write my own function could you help?

Comment: Please `dput()` a sample of your data and post the code you have tried so far. Thanks

Comment: your function has nothing to do with the data structure or even the data you have. Just write a `sd_w` function and use it exactly the same way you are using `wtd.var` etc. Do you know how to write a function? then just simply implement the weighted sd without thinking of the data that you have.

Comment: this it the function I currently have for obatining the weighted variance, so my values are from column 4997 to column 5188, and respective weights are in 5 to 196. dfinal$x_var <-  apply(dfinal,1, function(x){wtd.var(x[4997:5188], x[5:196], na.rm =TRUE)})

Comment: How do i write a function to integrate the formula? In the weighted variance formula, I will need to determine N', which is the number of weights that are different from 0. how can I determine this because this number should be dependent on if respective value is NA or not. If value is NA then the respective weight should be ignored.

Comment: Start with a small reproducible example in valid R syntax - not a screenshot of a spreadsheet. Perhaps something like `values = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,NA); weights = c(2, 0, 3, 1, 1,0,4)`. Figure out what the expected answer is. Then start writing a function. *"I will need to determine N', which is the number of weights that are different from 0. how can I determine this?"* Maybe something like `N = sum(weights[!is.na(values)]`. See if that works. Adjust as needed.

Comment: yay, I was able to adjust the formula, thank you so much for all of your comments